# Nothing happens when I try to generate a key in GITbash

Tags: git, ssh, key, git-bash

I am trying to generate ssh key in gitbash but when I copy pasted the message from the github website it is not generating the next steps as it shows in their 'generating the key' section. It just shows a $ sign and m blinking cursor like waiting for the next command. Am I missing something?
Please help

Trying to generate ssh key in gitbash

input: ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "pramodkalagara@gmail.com"

output: $

Please help

Why is it not generating the key?

Answer (score 0):

To verify if the key was generated, you can navigate to the default SSH key directory by entering the following command:

```
cd ~/.ssh
```

or

```
cd "C:\Users\<YOUR USER NAME>\.ssh"
```

[image] As you can see this is mine default directory for .ssh

If the key was successfully generated, you should see two files: id_ed25519 (private key) and id_ed25519.pub (public key). These files are the SSH key pair you need for authentication.